# speed of divergence of $\prod_{m=1}^n (\frac{z}{m} + 1)^m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, riemann-zeta, products

I would like to find the speed of divergence of $\prod_{m=1}^n (\frac{z}{m} + 1)^m$ for any $z$. For example, if $|z| < 1$, doing taylor expansion we know that it is roughly $e^{zn}.$ But I need it for all $z$ such that $\mathrm{Re}(z) > -1.$

Comment: If $|e^z|\ne 1$,it is not roughly $e^{z n}$.As $n\to \infty$ the product of $n$ terms, with the terms converging to $1$, cannot be approximately the product of $n$ terms, each equal  to $e^z$. Take  the log of the expression.Use the power series for $\log (1+x).$

Comment: What I meant, is that $\sum_{m=1}^n m \log(\frac{z}{m} + 1) = \sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k (-1)^k}{k m^{k-1}} .$ for $|z|<1.$ But I can't do Taylor for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$. So I would like to know whether I can find closed formula for every $z$.

Comment: Given z, you have a power series for log(1+z/m)  for  all sufficiently large m. (m greater than |z|.) For large m, we have log (1+z/m)=z/m+O(1/m^2).

Comment: What if $z$ is of order $n$?

Comment: i thought z was constant. You should add that in the Q, that z  is a function of n.